simpler method for finding word associations?
I am trying to build a word finder where when I input a word, it will search for an associated word from my list of words and return it. the idea is that any word can be input and any which closely relate an item in the list will have output.
My first thought was to use cosine similarity and a sentence transformer to map the trajectories.
code
reference_list = ["Fantasy", "Horror", "Romance", "Action"]

st = SentenceTransformer(model)
reference_dict = {word: st.encode(word) for word in reference_list}

def find_reference_word(myword, reference_dict):
    myword_vector = st.encode(myword)

    check_dict = {}
    for key, vector in reference_dict.items():
        cosine = np.dot(myword_vector, vector)/(norm(myword_vector)*norm(vector))
        if cosine > 0.6:
             check_dict[key] = cosine
    if check_dict:
        closest = max(check_dict, key=check_dict.get)
    return closest

while this works and does what I want, I can see that this would become a very slow process if my reference list grows.
I considered building a prediction model using one of the modules from scikit learn but going through the different methods, it seemed like my question might not be best answered here. I also thought about an LLM or looking into building a specialized version.

you save all matches in check_dict and then you look for the best match in that dict. You could instead keep track of the current best match "on the fly" and remove check_dict. If you're looking for a completely different approach, you might get better answers on Cross Validated

Traversing the vocabulary list has O(N) complexity. A possible solution to facilitate it would be perturbing the input embedding arbitrarily with a controlled magnitude and angle; As a result, the produced embedding has a higher chance to be similar to the input word. However, it is not possible to ensure the resulting embedding always decodes into a valid or meaningful word. Here we could find the most similar word based on the embedding and double check if it exists in your reference list. Although this is also O(N), it would be faster when the reference list is large.
import numpy as np
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
import enchant  # for dictionary check

# Load pre-trained word vectors
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('path_to_your_model', binary=True)

# English Dictionary or replace with reference list
dictionary = enchant.Dict("en_US")

def perturb_embedding(embedding, angle_rad, magnitude=0.1):
    dim = len(embedding)
    random_direction = np.random.randn(dim)
    random_direction /= np.linalg.norm(random_direction)  # Normalize the direction vector

    # Applying the angle in the perturbation, targeting decrement in cosine similarity
    perturbation = magnitude * np.cos(angle_rad) * embedding + magnitude * np.sin(angle_rad) * random_direction
    new_embedding = embedding + perturbation
    new_embedding /= np.linalg.norm(new_embedding)  # Normalize the perturbed vector
    return new_embedding

def get_modified_embeddings(word, lower_angle_deg=90, upper_angle_deg=180, n_samples=1000):
    original_embedding = model[word]
    modified_embeddings = []

    # Vary angles from lower_angle_deg to upper_angle_deg to statistically reduce cosine similarity
    angles_rad = np.radians(np.linspace(lower_angle_deg, upper_angle_deg, n_samples))

    for angle_rad in angles_rad:
        new_embedding = perturb_embedding(original_embedding, angle_rad)
        if cosine(original_embedding, new_embedding) < 0.6:
            modified_embeddings.append(new_embedding)

    return modified_embeddings

def decode_embeddings(embeddings, model):
    words = []
    for embedding in embeddings:
        # Find the closest word in the model to this embedding
        most_similar_word, _ = model.similar_by_vector(embedding, topn=1)[0]
        if dictionary.check(most_similar_word):
            words.append(most_similar_word)
    
    return words

# Usage:
word = "king"  # example word
modified_embeddings = get_modified_embeddings(word)
decoded_words = decode_embeddings(modified_embeddings, model)

print(decoded_words)

